# Automatically mapping the entity labels in an utterance through api using node Js

Tags: node.js, azure-language-understanding

Considering I'm having the simple entity named 'TurnOn' and I have trained it with the word 'on' so In Luis whenever I'm using the word `on` it labels it as 'TurnOn' entity, but I'm adding the utterance through API's using node js it doesn't capture the `on` as 'TurnON' entity, and I had marked the label by specifying the `entityName,startCharIndex`, `endIndex` in the entity tables parameter, but I wanna make it capture automatically can anyone tell me that how to do it.

Comment: Which LUIS doc are you using that uses startIndex and endIndex?

Answer (score 1):

The correct JSON is specified in the [API](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c09). Do not use startIndex or endIndex. Instead, use startCharIndex, and endCharIndex, an exmaple follows

```
[{
  "text": "go to Seattle today",
  "intentName": "BookFlight",
  "entityLabels": [
    {
      "entityName": "Location::LocationTo",
      "startCharIndex": 6,
      "endCharIndex": 12
    }
  ]
},
{
    "text": "a barking dog is annoying",
    "intentName": "None",
    "entityLabels": []
}]
```

Comment: sorry, I wrongly wrote it as startIndex and endIndex, but after few training it should automatically label the entities right, why we always need to label the entities and if I'm using the phrase list and simple entity the entity should labeled based on the words in the phrase list right, those thing is also not wroking when I'm training through API.

Answer (score 0):

> but I wanna make it capture automatically can anyone tell me that how to do it

I think you might be confusing the purposes of the training endpoints and the prediction endpoint. If you supply a utterance via the LUIS Programmatic API you are expected to provide the metadata about that utterance, such as the name of the intent, and the location of the entities.

If you don't provide the location (start and end) of the entities, and label them, LUIS will understand that as you are saying that the given utterance has no entities. Which can cause issues with your model.

LUIS will only try to detect and give you the entities when you are using the prediction endpoint. If you think about it, It doesn't make a lot of sense to provide the training data and want LUIS to make assumptions about that.